# Vite/react app uploaded in vercel, adding domain at the beginning on evert http request

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rest, vite, vercel

I have an vite/react application uploaded on vercel hosting, this application works woth REST Api backend written in express.js.
In application I have such requests:

```
fetch('api_url/users') // Get users list
fetch('api_url/users/:userId') // Get user details
```

It works fine with `api_url/users` request but when I sending request to `api_url/users/:userId` it adding vercel domain ath the beginning, request looks like:

```
fetch('https://my-app.vercel.app/api_url/users/:userId')
```

If you guys have such problem, please help me((

I tried to add rewrites to `vercel.json` file but it not works, my vercel configuration file looks like this:

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/users/:path*", "destination": "/users/:path*" },
    { "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }
  ]
}
```